# How to send boolean in formData?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

I am sending a file with a boolean flag to the backend from React frontend like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('zip_file', file);
formData.append('flag', false);
```

But in the backend I am getting the flag as:

```
'flag': ['false']
```

I searched online and then tried this:

```
formData.append('flag', JSON.stringify(false));
```

But, still I am getting the same response in the backend. What am I doing wrong, and what is the best way to send file as well as some data to backend.

Comment: Is your backend variable type boolean??

Comment: Yes I want boolean as flag in the backend

Comment: I asked what is the type of the backend variable? I do this on a regular basis and never has any issue. I have .net core backend which uses modal binding.